# Jackson for android ADT 17

Tags: android

I am new in android, I am using jackson-all-1.9.4 jar in my application for android ADT 16. 
My application working fine. But after i take update for android ADT 17, it gives force close and shows error on logcat like this,

```
04-02 08:54:47.302: E/AndroidRuntime(234): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
```

what is the problem here, android ADT 17 does not support jackson-all-1.9.4 jar?

any one can help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817372/updated-sdk-tools-and-adt-to-17-and-now-getting-verifyerrors see this link..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716 see this answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the exact same problem. Check this blog post: http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

tl;dr: Rename your lib directory to libs and add Jackson to the project again.