# Android update 17 seems incompatible with external Jars

Tags: java, android, macos

I just allowed my Mac to do an update on its Java installation and now some of my old jars (like `javax.mail` and `apache.commons.httpclient`) are throwing *"class not found"* exceptions at run time!

Meaning, they compile fine, but then crash at run time with exceptions that look like this:

```
E/dalvikvm(2414): Could not find class 'javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress', referenced from method com.my.project.Main.isValidEmailAddress
```

Do I need to get more recent versions of the jars that have those classes? Or do I need to revert to my previous version of Java?

Or is this some totally unrelated problem that I'm just assuming has to do with the Java update *(would be quite a coincidence, all of this worked perfectly prior to the update)*?

Comment: are u talking about external jar files ?

Comment: yes, specifically I've been using apache-commons 3.0 and that appears to no longer be compatible.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> crash at run time with exceptions that look like this:
>   `Could not find class 'javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress', referenced from method com.my.project.Main.isValidEmailAddress`

If you have problems with external jars, then:

1. create a folder named `libs`.
2. Copy and paste all needed external jar files into that folder.

It will automatically be included, as explained on this page: [Dealing with dependencies in Android projects](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects)

Comment: try this because i have also face problem like this and solved bu putting all jar files in libs folder

Comment: But whenever I am updating the ADT, it is asking to update SDK. And after updating its showing "An error has occurred. See error log for more details. com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.getName()Ljava/lang/String; ". If uninstallation is the solution, then how do I update the ADT as well as SDK tools? I uninstall and reinstall this to solve this issue many times. But how do I update all and run the build successfully? Its really required.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, isn't this the same as the Referenced Libraries section of the project? My eclipse was handling this just fine and now all of the sudden I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me but my folder was labeled "lib" instead of "libs" arg! updating was a little rough this time around... fixed after removing the external jars from the project settings and changing the folder to libs

Answer (score 1):

If renaming the `lib` to `libs` doesn't work then try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831019/updated-sdk-version-getting-classnotfoundexception-android-support-v4-view-vie).