# apple bonjour for android

Tags: android, bonjour, jmdns

I m looking for an apple bonjour for android.
Are there a recommanded jar for this?

I googled for an apple bonjour application and I found the Jmdns application http://home.heeere.com/tech-androidjmdns.html.

but when running the **DEMO** application, a bug appear in the launch of the application. here after the Eclipse LogCat:

```
09-05 13:56:49.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13243): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.jmdns.JmDNS
09-05 13:56:49.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13243):    at com.heeere.android.dnssdtuto.DnssdDiscovery.setUp(DnssdDiscovery.java:44)
09-05 13:56:49.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13243):    at com.heeere.android.dnssdtuto.DnssdDiscovery.access$0(DnssdDiscovery.java:38)
09-05 13:56:49.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13243):    at com.heeere.android.dnssdtuto.DnssdDiscovery$1.run(DnssdDiscovery.java:27)
09-05 13:56:49.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13243):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-05 13:56:49.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13243):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-05 13:56:49.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13243):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-05 13:56:49.926: E/AndroidRuntime(13243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
```

Java code:

```
package com.heeere.android.dnssdtuto;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.jmdns.JmDNS;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceEvent;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceInfo;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DnssdDiscovery extends Activity {

    android.net.wifi.WifiManager.MulticastLock lock;
    android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setUp();
            }
            }, 1000);

    }    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    private String type = "_workspace._tcp.local.";
    private JmDNS jmdns = null;
    private ServiceListener listener = null;
    private ServiceInfo serviceInfo;
    private void setUp() {
        android.net.wifi.WifiManager wifi = (android.net.wifi.WifiManager) getSystemService(android.content.Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("mylockthereturn");
        lock.setReferenceCounted(true);
        lock.acquire();
        try {
            jmdns = JmDNS.create();
            jmdns.addServiceListener(type, listener = new ServiceListener() {

                public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent ev) {
                    notifyUser("Service resolved: " + ev.getInfo().getQualifiedName() + " port:" + ev.getInfo().getPort());
                }

                public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent ev) {
                    notifyUser("Service removed: " + ev.getName());
                }

                public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) {
                    // Required to force serviceResolved to be called again (after the first search)
                    jmdns.requestServiceInfo(event.getType(), event.getName(), 1);
                }
            });
            serviceInfo = ServiceInfo.create("_test._tcp.local.", "AndroidTest", 0, "plain test service from android");
            jmdns.registerService(serviceInfo);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }


    private void notifyUser(final String msg) {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        t.setText(msg+"\n=== "+t.getText());
            }
            }, 1);

    }

    @Override
        protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //new Thread(){public void run() {setUp();}}.start();
    }

    @Override
        protected void onStop() {
        if (jmdns != null) {
            if (listener != null) {
                jmdns.removeServiceListener(type, listener);
                listener = null;
            }
            jmdns.unregisterAllServices();
            try {
                jmdns.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jmdns = null;
        }
        //repo.stop();
        //s.stop();
        lock.release();
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.heeere.android.dnssdtuto"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".DnssdDiscovery"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: pls post your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the [Jmdns example site](http://home.heeere.com/tech-androidjmdns.html),  published a new example of Jmdns that works without problem. I have tested with the Jmdns 3.4.1 from [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C1991004139) and It works

this [link](https://github.com/twitwi/AndroidDnssdDemo/tree/master/AndroidDnssdDiscoveryCommandLine) is the new example of Jmdns

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem 
then i replaced jmdns.jar with maven jmdns 3.4.1.jar 
[Click to download](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/archive-details/javax/jmdns/jmdns/3.4.1/jmdns-3.4.1-sources.jar)

if you will get dalvik error on start up try to remove jar file from build path and other folder 
keep this file in libs folder,
may be this will helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

Make a folder called "libs", put the jar in that folder, and try.

Comment: I can see that eclipse see the jar file. and there is no problem in the built. the problem is an exception error when starting the application

Comment: I can see the problem is a NoDefClassFoundError. Something similar happened to me with other .jar. That exception happens when the class is not reachable, so despite you might think, Eclipse is not finding that class. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070788/noclassdeffonderror-in-android-but-the-class-is-in-one-jar-included-in-the-cl . Making the "libs" folder fixed it for me. In my case, Eclipse didn't show any error in compilation, but failed in execution.

Answer (score 0):

Add this jar to your project, clean build and try again :

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/jmdns/jmdns/3.2.2/jmdns-3.2.2.jar

Comment: Did you add it to your build path ?

Comment: the build is OK, but when running an exception error appear at the start-up of the application