# Trouble in getting the meaning of the name in android

Tags: android, jsoup

I am new with android development.I am creating an app that will tell the meaning of name entered by user, for this I am using www.babynamesworld.parentsconnect.com to fetch the data and parse the meaning of name out of it.Here is the code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {

            TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://babynamesworld.parentsconnect.com/meaning_of_"+et.getText().toString()+".html").get();
                    Element firstMeta = document.select("meta").first();
                     String title = firstMeta.attr("DESCRIPTION"); 
                     tv.setText(title);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        }});



    }
```

As soon I click on the button, program crashes. I've added internet access permission too.

Comment: Post the stack trace (do it **always**).

Comment: What is exception you got, check it in logcat

Comment: @m0skito as I said I'm new, where can i get stack trace??

Comment: "04-10 18:51:19.031: E/AndroidRuntime(5851): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup"
This is something i got in the logcat, maybe i've done something wrong while importing JSOUP

Comment: If you don't know what a stack trace is, maybe you could do a little more Java development research. It would probably go a long way. I mean this in a nice way. Without more details it looks like an issue could be that you are not including a needed .jar file in your actual project.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i have imported the jsoup.jar file in the project, its even showing in the package explorer

Comment: clean the project and rerun it, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question "How can i clean the project?"

Comment: one another problem, how can i retrieve "The meaning of the name Pramod is 'Joy;" from this:

<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="The meaning of the name Pramod is 'Joy;" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Virtual Machine can't find the `Jsoup` class definitions. Have you included either the source files or a jar in your project?

If you've already added the jar try cleaning the project.

Comment: yes I've included jsoup.jar through Project>Properties>Java Buil Path>Libraries>Add External Jars 
Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: If you using the newest version (ADT r17) you have to choose antoher way to add the lib to your project. Look here [Adding lib in r17](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046298/android-update-17-seems-incompatible-with-external-jars)

Comment: @sandkasten already solved the problem, cleaning worked, thanks anyways