# android exception even though the jdom library is there

Tags: android, eclipse, jdom, eclipse-adt

[image]

The jdom library is there and i have removed and added it again and again to the build path. And, i have cleaned the project as well many times. But still iam getting this error:

```
 04-27 10:51:27.867: W/ActivityThread(530): Application com.pkg.src.nhs.glos is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
    04-27 10:51:27.936: I/System.out(530): Sending WAIT chunk
    04-27 10:51:29.396: I/dalvikvm(530): Debugger is active
    04-27 10:51:29.736: I/System.out(530): Debugger has connected
    04-27 10:51:29.746: I/System.out(530): waiting for debugger to settle...
    04-27 10:51:29.996: I/System.out(530): waiting for debugger to settle...
    04-27 10:51:30.262: I/System.out(530): waiting for debugger to settle...
    04-27 10:51:30.479: I/System.out(530): waiting for debugger to settle...
    04-27 10:51:30.689: I/System.out(530): waiting for debugger to settle...
    04-27 10:51:30.896: I/System.out(530): waiting for debugger to settle...
    04-27 10:51:43.786: D/dalvikvm(553): GC freed 683 objects / 60040 bytes in 110ms
    04-27 10:51:49.396: W/dalvikvm(553): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/androidquery/AQuery;)
    04-27 10:51:49.576: W/dalvikvm(553): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/androidquery/util/XmlDom;)
    04-27 10:51:49.646: W/dalvikvm(553): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/androidquery/callback/AjaxStatus;)
    04-27 10:51:49.646: I/dalvikvm(553): Could not find method com.androidquery.util.XmlDom.tags, referenced from method com.pkg.src.nhs.glos.MainActivity.setImageCallBack
    04-27 10:51:49.646: W/dalvikvm(553): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 80: Lcom/androidquery/util/XmlDom;.tags (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;
    04-27 10:51:49.646: D/dalvikvm(553): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0013
    04-27 10:51:49.646: D/dalvikvm(553): Making a copy of Lcom/pkg/src/nhs/glos/MainActivity;.setImageCallBack code (200 bytes)
    04-27 10:51:50.126: E/dalvikvm(553): Could not find class 'org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder', referenced from method com.pkg.src.nhs.glos.MainActivity$SetImageTask.doInBackground
    04-27 10:51:50.126: W/dalvikvm(553): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 166 (Lorg/jdom/input/SAXBuilder;) in Lcom/pkg/src/nhs/glos/MainActivity$SetImageTask;
    04-27 10:51:50.126: D/dalvikvm(553): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0009
    04-27 10:51:50.126: D/dalvikvm(553): Making a copy of Lcom/pkg/src/nhs/glos/MainActivity$SetImageTask;.doInBackground code (205 bytes)
    04-27 10:51:50.736: W/dalvikvm(553): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
    04-27 10:51:50.746: E/AndroidRuntime(553): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #1 exiting due to uncaught exception
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.pkg.src.nhs.glos.MainActivity$SetImageTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:100)
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.pkg.src.nhs.glos.MainActivity$SetImageTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    04-27 10:51:50.846: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  ... 4 more
    04-27 10:51:50.941: I/dalvikvm(553): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
    04-27 10:51:50.941: E/dalvikvm(553): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
    04-27 10:52:02.038: I/Process(553): Sending signal. PID: 553 SIG: 9
```

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Comment: Is the library in your libs folder?

Comment: thanks you should appreciate that ans

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if the jdom library is checked in the Order and Export Tab of your build path Settings.
If it is not check it, do a clean and retry to run your application.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio it must automatically added the jar files which you added to the "libs" folder in your project,but sometimes it doesn't do that.
So you have to go to "Project Structure" = ctrl+alt+shift+S for Windows users.

Then click "app" at the left side of the panel.
Then click Dependencies tab.
Then click on (+) -> jar dependencies.
Then in the libs folder choose your jar file.

Then click OK.

Comment: Actually this is the bug of the android studio.