# android code is crashing no errors

Tags: android, crash, logcat

hi to all can any one please tell me what is the problem from this logcat

once the app opens the image gallery to pick an image the app crashes

(what the code does: it opens the image gallery and loads the image as a wall paper then the user can ad an hair or a star ...etc to the image....)

thanks to all :)

```
E/dalvikvm(14530): Could not find class 'com.google.ads.AdView', referenced from method com.owleyes.moustache.Viewer.basicInit
W/dalvikvm(14530): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(14530): java.lang.VerifyError: com.owleyes.moustache.Viewer
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1024)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
E/AndroidRuntime(14530):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(14530): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(14530): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: `Could not find class 'com.google.ads.AdView'` It's the first line.

Comment: What do you mean by "no errors" in title?

Comment: Do you added the AdMob Library Jar?

Comment: the code has no errors no red x's

Comment: yes I have androidAdmobsdk6.2.1.jar included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Java Build Path, click the Export & Order tab to see if that jar file is checked. Make sure it is checked so the Admob jar file is packaged in the APK file.

Answer (score 0):

In your method com.owleyes.moustache.Viewer.basicInit you're referencing com.google.ads.AdView. You are probably missing a library in the libs folder.

Without posting more of your code no one is going to really be able to help you any more than that.

Answer (score 0):

GoogleAdMobsAdsSDK is not attached to your project or it is attached in the wrong way. The easiest way to solve this problem is to copy the library to libs folder.

There is already topic on SO that concerns similar issue. Check this out for more info:
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.ads.AdView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353479/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-ads-adview)