# Multiple DEX files in library

Tags: android, google-play-services

I wrote an android app, added `Google-play-services` lib to it, then ran it. Then I got this error:

```
[2015-10-16 12:34:32 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
[2015-10-16 12:34:32 - HelloCordova] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
```

My `Lib` structure is:
[image: img]
Is jar file and library conflicting each other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958979/multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-google-ads-adrequesterrorcode-and-multiple-dex-f

Comment: Oh... should I remove `PayPalAndroidSDK-2.9.11.jar`?

Comment: I checked `java build path`. I've `google-play-services.jar` in my build path. Should I remove it?

Comment: Why you people not using `Android Studio`? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `PayPalAndroidSDK-2.9.11.jar` from `lib`. Looks like I was using new `google-play-services`.

Comment: I guess you overcome this