# Adding google play services library to Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services, cordova-plugins, dex

I have added google play services library in my project built using Cordova. The command I used to add plugin is:

```
cordova plugin add com.google.playservices
```

After adding it, when I build my project, I get below error:

[image]

I am not using Admob in my project, then why I am getting dex issue. Nor I have added google play services in the project. I have only added the google play services plugin.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958979/multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-google-ads-adrequesterrorcode-and-multiple-dex-f

Comment: I am not using AdMob, hence the link you shared is not answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the DexException must be imported via terminal this plugin :

**cordova plugin add https://github.com/jwall149/cordova-multidex**