# Google ADView class not found exception even after adding play service

Tags: android, google-play-services

Recently i updated my android sdk tool to 23.2 after that am getting continues class not found exception while running google ad demo project.I can able to open the class file of ADView when i click on the import link ,still don't know what went wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
07-15 10:55:52.051: E/AndroidRuntime(5126): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
07-15 10:55:52.051: E/AndroidRuntime(5126):     at com.google.example.gms.ads.banner.BannerSample.onCreate(BannerSample.java:28)
07-15 10:55:52.051: E/AndroidRuntime(5126):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353479/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-ads-adview

Comment: @Arash This was working before updating the sdk also the the ad service now moved to play service so there is no need of libs folder

Comment: Fixed the issue by moving the play service library from sdk folder to some other one and import into the workspace

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by moving the play service library from sdk folder to some other one and import into the workspace