# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ayc for InterstitialAd

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

If found that the users which use old devices (2.3.6) send me this uncatched exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ayc
at ajb.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:20)
at po.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:536)
at po.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:144)
at qn.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:150)
at pm.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:312)
at ul.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:81)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzu$zza$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzac.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.loadAd(Unknown Source)
at my.app.q.g(ABase.java:196)
at my.app.q.f(ABase.java:183)
at my.app.q.onCreate(ABase.java:88)
at my.app.AMain.onCreate(AMain.java:53)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3770)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code at error line is this:

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
//... some defenitions
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);/// <<< THE ERROR APPEARS
```

Is it possible to fix this bug without wrapping try-(catch Exception e)-finally?

Comment: Can you show your `gradle` ?

Comment: Are you sure you've `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-package.` checked ? like here in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10632156/5067493) answer.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna , I'm using Eclipse. This code works in all other devices exapt very old. I'm using up-to-date Google SDK libs.

Comment: @Tony, nope. I do not understand the core of the error.

Comment: @Vyacheslav me neither, I have several apps suffering from same error. All of them are between version 2.3.3 and 23.7

Comment: Does it occur only on GB devices? How often does it occur? Can you please provide more statistics and maybe write them on this bug report: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/_kYrMS5nVxE ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an SDK issue, rather than something wrong in your code.

The release of Play services that just rolled out contains a Mobile Ads bug that affects devices running Gingerbread. Engineering's aware of it, a fix has been created, and it will go out in the next release.

Comment: I've created a bug report for this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/_kYrMS5nVxE . BTW, it happens to me, and I use normal banner ads (no InterstitialAd )

Answer (score 3):

This is what I was told in the [**bug report**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/_kYrMS5nVxE) of this issue:

> As you are probably aware, the cause of the crash was SDK-related.  A
>   fix is in the pipeline, and scheduled to go live in the next SDK
>   release.

And later:

> The most recent release of Google Play services contains a bug
>   affecting devices running Gingerbread. The SDK team has identified the
>   problem and created a server-side workaround that should eliminate it.
>   These crashes should tail off in the coming days, so you should expect
>   to see fewer and fewer of them going forward.

So, this is being fixed via the server, and you will get less reports till it reaches 0%.

Wish all bugs were handled this way :)