# Java Libraries Missing in Eclipse Android Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, rmi

So I've been given the tedious task of trying to do some updates on an old Android project of an ex grad student at my University, and I am having some bizarre behaviour with the project. I am told that the project used to work perfectly, but I've been having nothing but headaches with it.

One problem in particular frequently comes and goes. Namely, the project forgets what a couple of libraries are. "import java.rmi cannot be resolved", likewise Eclipse does not recognise "org.omg". But here's the tricky thing- it sometimes recognises them. I will recreate the project, or play around with the class path, or reboot my machine, and then the error will vanish and the project can run. There are further problems down the line, but at least it can compile. But then the error creeps back, I try to do the same things I did before to make it go away, but it will persist. But then, I leave it for a bit, come back a day or two later, and the problem seems arbitrarily (and temporarily) fixed.

Any idea as to what would cause this kind of behaviour?

Comment: I always found `org.omg` a ridiculous package name.  It always makes me think of a young teen going 'Oh my gawd'.  More seriously, what version of Eclipse are you running, what version of JVM are you running, and what does the project depend on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716 see this that may help u

Comment: Eclipse classic version 3.7.2, Java version is 1.6.0_31

Comment: Unfortunately, putting all the project JARs into a libs folder did not help, and they've been explicitly imported into the project anyway.

Comment: What Android SDK and ADT version do you use, referencing from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html)?

Comment: The min Android SDK is Android 8, but I have the same problems with Android 15. ADT version is 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853