# Suddenly get ClassNotFoundException in Exception

Tags: android, eclipse, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I finally switched from Helios to Indigo.
Suddenly I am getting ClassNotFoundException popping up.

```
05-02 16:05:22.621: W/System.err(21126): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
05-02 16:05:22.631: W/System.err(21126):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
05-02 16:05:22.631: W/System.err(21126):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-02 16:05:22.631: W/System.err(21126):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
05-02 16:05:22.631: W/System.err(21126):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-02 16:05:22.631: W/System.err(21126):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-02 16:05:22.631: W/System.err(21126):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-02 16:05:22.631: W/System.err(21126):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
05-02 16:05:22.631: W/System.err(21126):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
05-02 16:05:22.631: W/System.err(21126):    at ui.YanivMenuActivity.onCreate(YanivMenuActivity.java:43)
05-02 16:05:22.631: W/System.err(21126):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-02 16:05:22.631: W/System.err(21126):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
05-02 16:05:22.641: W/System.err(21126):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
05-02 16:05:22.641: W/System.err(21126):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
05-02 16:05:22.641: W/System.err(21126):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
05-02 16:05:22.641: W/System.err(21126):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 16:05:22.641: W/System.err(21126):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 16:05:22.641: W/System.err(21126):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
05-02 16:05:22.641: W/System.err(21126):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 16:05:22.641: W/System.err(21126):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-02 16:05:22.641: W/System.err(21126):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
05-02 16:05:22.641: W/System.err(21126):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
05-02 16:05:22.651: W/System.err(21126):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 16:05:22.651: W/System.err(21126): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/il.co.anykey.games.cardking.basic-1.apk]
05-02 16:05:22.651: W/System.err(21126):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-02 16:05:22.651: W/System.err(21126):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-02 16:05:22.651: W/System.err(21126):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-02 16:05:22.661: W/System.err(21126):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
05-02 16:05:22.661: W/System.err(21126):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
05-02 16:05:22.661: W/System.err(21126):    ... 21 more
```

This is my classpath file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/MultiPlayerGameControl/src" sourcepath="/MultiPlayerGameControl/src"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/CardKingLib/src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Program Files/Android/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkAndroid-4.1.0/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Program Files/Android/ScoreLoop/ScoreloopCore/jar/scoreloop-core.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="E:/Program Files/Android/AdWhirlSDK_Android_3.1.1/AdWhirlSDK_Android_3.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="/MultiPlayerGameControl"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/CardKingLib"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="E:/Program Files/Android/heyzap-sdk-2.0.1/heyzap-sdk-2.0.1/android-sdk/heyzap-sdk-2.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Comment: Awesome! Please add it as an answer so I can mark it up and choose it as best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have problems with external jars

then create one folder named **libs**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716