# How to use epublib jar in my android application

Tags: android, eclipse, epub, epublib

I have implemented one application in android which uses epublib to view .epub files.

http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android

As per this link, I have done following steps.

> Slf4j-android.
>   You can download this at http://www.slf4j.org/android/

Getting started

> Download epublib-core-latest.jar from https://github.com/downloads/psiegman/epublib/epublib-core-latest.jar
>       Download slf4j-android
>       Add both to your android project

Complete e-book reader with sourcecode.

I am using Eclipse SDK Version: 3.7.2.

I am getting this error at runtime : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader.

I have used below mention code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Book;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.TOCReference;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Log the info of 'assets/books/testbook.epub'.
 *
 * @author paul.siegmann
 *
 */
public class LogTestBookInfo extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    try {
      // find InputStream for book
      InputStream epubInputStream = assetManager
          .open("books/testbook.epub");

      // Load Book from inputStream
      Book book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);

      // Log the book's authors
      Log.i("epublib", "author(s): " + book.getMetadata().getAuthors());

      // Log the book's title
      Log.i("epublib", "title: " + book.getTitle());

      // Log the book's coverimage property
      Bitmap coverImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(book.getCoverImage()
          .getInputStream());
      Log.i("epublib", "Coverimage is " + coverImage.getWidth() + " by "
          + coverImage.getHeight() + " pixels");

      // Log the tale of contents
      logTableOfContents(book.getTableOfContents().getTocReferences(), 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("epublib", e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  /**
   * Recursively Log the Table of Contents
   *
   * @param tocReferences
   * @param depth
   */
  private void logTableOfContents(List<TOCReference> tocReferences, int depth) {
    if (tocReferences == null) {
      return;
    }
    for (TOCReference tocReference : tocReferences) {
      StringBuilder tocString = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
        tocString.append("\t");
      }
      tocString.append(tocReference.getTitle());
      Log.i("epublib", tocString.toString());

      logTableOfContents(tocReference.getChildren(), depth + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Please give me some solution.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have problems with external jars then create one folder named libs

Answer (score 0):

You should create one folder named "libs". Then copy and paste all needed jar files in that folder. The jar files will be automatically included