# Adding microsoft excel jar file in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

How to add excel jar Libraries in Eclipse and which jar file should i add and where to add in eclipse.  please provide me full details.
 i already check in this site but i am not getting any ideal. http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath

please provide me external site that should show step by step process.

i have already added jxl-2.6 jar file . 
And please tell me the configuration of Emulator. Because i am getting an error

```
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.com/com.com.test}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.com.test in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.com-1.apk]
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.com.test in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.com-1.apk]
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-08 16:47:07.585: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
```

Comment: must see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046298/android-update-17-seems-incompatible-with-external-jars/10046725#10046725

Answer (score 0):

The error you included has nothing to do with the library you want to use.

It looks more that Android can not find your main activity class `com.com.test`. 
Please check `AndroidManifest.xml` if all activities specified here are really implemented.

If everything looks OK make sure to execute "Clean" from the "Project" menu in Eclipse - sometimes the Android plugin in Eclipse has some problems maintaining all files in the latest state.

Comment: please tell me about the excel api for android and which jar file should i use.

Comment: I don't see where your problem is. Just download the [latest 2.6.12 jexcelapi release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/files/jexcelapi/2.6.12/) and add the included **jxl.jar** to your project.