# User-Agent for osmdroid

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I tried to put the user agent (cf https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Important-notes-on-using-osmdroid-in-your-app), but when I put the line `OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants.setUserAgentValue(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);` Android studio is telling me that setUserAgentValue is depreciated.

What can I do to solve that ? For now when I run the app I have a grid with no map.

Thanks you very much in advance !

Comment: A deprecated method doesn't indicate it doesn't work. It just means that method may go away in a future version of the library. Does the first question of the FAQ help? https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's deprecated because it's been moved to another location which consolidates all configuration settings for osmdroid. Try the following

`Configuration.getInstance().setUserAgentValue(...)`

The older method was rewritten to wire it into the new configuration construct.

Comment: Thanks, this solve the problem with the depreciated class !

But the problem is that I still have just a grid and no map. (In fact my problem is the same of this subject : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020570/no-map-shown-in-osmdroid , that why I was trying to set the user agent)

Thanks in advance