# No map displayed in app using OpenStreetMap (android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I tried to do make an osmdroid project using the code from

[No map shown in osmdroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020570/no-map-shown-in-osmdroid)

I also set the User-Agent (see [User-Agent for osmdroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152016/user-agent-for-osmdroid) )

The problem is thas there are still no map shown. I have just a blanck grid.

I searched a lot on the internet for solutions but I did'nt find any. When I See the tutorials I didn't understand why it is not working well.

Thanks you very much in advance for your help, best regards

Comment: can you add any more context to this? sample code? did you see the sample app on github? any relevant logcat info?

Comment: Dear spy, thank you very much for your answer. The codes are the same that the one in this subject : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020570/no-map-shown-in-osmdroid

Comment: On the logcat I have a huge quantity of that kind of messages:

`04-09 20:47:30.375 12874-13936/test.osmapp D/OsmDroid: Unable to store cached tile from Mapnik /14/8336/5844, database not available.
04-09 20:47:30.396 12874-13936/test.osmapp I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:0
04-09 20:47:30.397 12874-13936/test.osmapp I/System.out: [CDS]SO_SND_TIMEOUT:0
04-09 20:47:30.397 12874-13936/test.osmapp I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
04-09 20:47:30.397 12874-13936/test.osmapp I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<`

Comment: Most likely permissions. Did you try that yet?

Comment: It's works thanks, the problem was I had to manually authorize the app to store data on my phone. Is there any way to make the app asking it automatically ?