# Attaching the source of an external jar file

Tags: android

I want to attach the source code to an external `jar` file that I have. Normally I would just got to `configure build path`, expand the jar file and edit the source attachment. But since the jar file is an `Android Dependency` it does not give me that option.

so I have 2 questions then, How can I attach the source to an android dependency or how can I make the jar file not an android dependency so I can attach it like i normally would?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Comment: The link doesn't help, the issue is not adding the external JAR, it's that when Android re-compiles the JAR it looses the link to source and prevents stepping into source code.