# NoClassDefFoundError on MultiPart compilable method in Android

Tags: android, image, http, multipart

I'm dealing with the following problem: when trying to upload an image through MultiPart Entity and it seems that the several updates on HttpClient/MIME are cracking everything. I'm trying the following code, but it fails with a `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
public static void executeMultipartPost(File image, ArrayList<Cookie> cookies, String myUrlToPost) {
    try {
        // my post instance
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(myUrlToPost);
        // setting cookies for the connection session
        if (cookies != null && cookies.size() > 0) {
            String cookieString = "";
            for (int i=0; i<cookies.size(); ++i) {
                cookieString += cookies.get(i).getName()+"="+cookies.get(i).getValue()+";";
            }
            cookieString += "domain=" + BaseUrl + "; " + "path=/";
            httppost.addHeader("Cookie", cookieString);
        }
        // creating the http client
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // creating the multientity part [ERROR OCCURS IN THIS BELLOW LINE]
        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        multipartEntity.addPart("photoupload", new FileBody(image));
        httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

This method is fully compilable and uses the [httpclient-4.0.1.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0.1/httpclient-4.0.1.jar) and [httpmime-4.2.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.2-beta1/httpmime-4.2-beta1.jar) libs, but again, it crashes on the commented line for me.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi dark, thanks for the fast answer. Yeah, I seens to be reasonable to try a project cleaning. I've also cleaned it before, with no results. I believe (but not so sure) that he error comes from the updates in .jars, where it is in method missings or in conflicted versions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Comment: Interesting post, gtumca. I have just removed (unchecked) all my .jar files from the project and coincidentally, I'm getting a compile-time error in the line that I receive the error in the run/execution time. I gonna check it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?nebn6a3cxpmj4k6) you have libraries needed for Multipart post, all credits to **Satya Komatineni** and **David Maclean**, writers of Pro Android 3 and now 4 and I quote from their book

> To do multipart POST calls, you need  to get three additional Apache
>   open source projects: Apache Commons IO, Mime4j, and  HttpMime. You
>   can download these projects from the following web sites:   Commons
>   IO: http://commons.apache.org/io/  Mime4j:
>   http://james.apache.org/mime4j/  HttpMime:
>   http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi (inside of HttpClient)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and it was fixed by moving jars files into 'libs' directory in your android project.

Comment: Hi Sergey, thanks for the answer. My .jar files are already in the "libs" folder. Have you succeded in this multipart implementation? Which jars have you used? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean same problem with jar files and httpclient jar. I'm using httpClient indirectly, with asyncHttp project http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ which delivery jar library.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the jar is checked in the projects build path. (Project -> Properties)

Comment: Hi Phyx, thanks for the answer. My .jars are already all checked (inserted/integrated) in my project.