# Ksoap2 Runtime Exception SoapObject ClassDefNotFound in Android

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I am trying to use a .NET service in Android Application using the ksoap2 library.
I added the reference to the jar of ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies in my project.
But when I run the code I get a **runtime exception** saying

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFound : org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject.
```

Can anyone please help ?
This is my code.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
        new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        tvTemp.setText("Received :" + resultsRequestSOAP.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Comment: Your Welcome you can appreciate that by giving UP vote

Comment: already voted up your comment. :)

Comment: Thanks but Up vote to the answer dear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the link provided by the first commentator on the question. I am leaving the answer here just in case another programmer faces the same problem and comes across my question.

The solution to this problem is to create a folder named "libs" in the project directory and copying all the external jar files there.

For further explanation, one can refer to this link.
http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects