# How to link third party library (jar) into systerserver.java (services.jar) on Android?

Tags: android, jar, android-service

Now I already built a third party jar called telephony_DA.
And I already can use this telephony_DA library in application level. 
(modication on AndroidManifest.xml and add permission into /etc/permissions)

My problem is that I wrote a new service called TelephonyRegistry_DA.java in
    "com.android.server" 
package and used the classes from telephony_DA library.
After noting the telephony_DA library in Android.mk, I can built services library sucessfully.
But in run time it appearred crash with the reason of

```
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry_DA"
```

I tried to figure out the issue then I found something.
Once I remove the classes from telephony_DA library in TelephonyRegistry_DA.java then in run time there is no issue on creating and adding service from TelephonyRegistry_DA.java.
It seems that systemserver didn't know the link with telephony_DA library.

So how do I add a thirdparty jar into systemserver.java?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Answer (score 0):

In application level, you can inidcat 3rd party library from manifest.xml.
But in services from system server you should add 3rd party libary into default linking path. so please modify (ex: telephony_DA.jar) init.rc as below.

export BOOTCLASSPATH /system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/filterfw.jar:/system/framework/telephony_DA.jar