# Error when calling pure java code (separate project) from android in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have this simple java code:

```
package com.androiddesktoptest.testtest;

public class AndroidDesktopTestMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        callFromAndroid();
    }

    public static void callFromAndroid()
    {
        System.out.println("DESKTOP CODE CALLED FROM ANDROID");
    }
}
```

And I want to call it from Android like this:

```
import com.androiddesktoptest.testtest.AndroidDesktopTestMain;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //...
    AndroidDesktopTestMain.callFromAndroid();
}
```

and I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

I am using Eclipse and my project AndroidDesktopTest has checked to export AndroidDesktopTest/src. Also, eclipse autocomplete my code in Android, so it see correcly my code in desktop project.

What I am doing wrong? I did something like this in my previous-previous-previous project, from this time, maybe ADT has chaged or something...

*** UPDATE *** 
entire error
`07-20 14:02:56.452: E/AndroidRuntime(30233): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.androiddesktoptest.testtest.AndroidDesktopTestMain`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Comment: I don't have problem with jars, but with separated project.

Comment: 07-20 14:02:56.452: E/AndroidRuntime(30233): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.androiddesktoptest.testtest.AndroidDesktopTestMain

Comment: How are the 2 projects linked?

Comment: Anders Metnik - one project export source, and second (Android) has java project in "required project in the build path". Is it enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you don't get the class over to the phone when u run your android.

Make sure that:

right click project - properties - java build path - Order and Export (is it checked here?)

Comment: In order and export, move up your external project so it is almost at the top (right under your android project).

Comment: I think he is referring to the precedence of the library export order.

Comment: src is at the top from the beginnning

Comment: And after that needs to be your java project, else it won't reference it right when you load it onto the device.

Comment: Else attach a screenshot of it (the export order). And I can explain it out from that.

Comment: If it is unclear for anyone: you must export desktop code in desktop project AND android project.

Answer (score 3):

Order & Export isn't the most well built feature of the Android ADT.

If you instead include the linked src folder from the Desktop project to your Android project (Right Click Project > Build Path > Link Source Folder) then the Class will be used as if it belongs to the Android Project.

I think the prefered way of doing this would be to create a jar file or a Library Project but these might be too cumbersome to try until you have stable Deskptop code.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://geekswithblogs.net/cyberycon/archive/2011/05/17/using-external-libraries-with-android.aspx) about including Java libraries into Android projects suggests replacing the "JRE System Library" with the android.jar for your API level in your linked Java project's build path dialog.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
new AndroidDesktopTestMain.callFromAndroid();
```

The only way to call a non-static method from a static method is to have an instance of the class containing the non-static method. By definition, a non-static method is one that is called ON an instance of some class, whereas a static method belongs to the class itself.

Comment: What? public static void callFromAndroid()

Comment: I m not getting you.. Have you tried the above code? Is it working?

Comment: callFromAndroid is static, so I don't understand your answer... and yes, I tried it (look at another answer, same strange advice).