# Referencing android.jar in eclipse

Tags: android, dalvik

My requirement is to reference a modified `android.jar` into an android project. The new android.jar has some platform specific changes. When I tried to reference it as external jar, I'm getting the following error:

> Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

How can I use the new `android.jar` in my project?

Comment: did you try to add it in a libs folder in your application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Comment: I think you are referring two same jar files. Or two jar files having same classes in your application.

Comment: I added the jar file in libs folder and gave that path as referenced library..that worked! thanks

Comment: do you also update the sdk classes on the emulator or the device? the android.jar is only there to make eclipse happy, and it won't go into emulator/device automatically

Answer (score 0):

Add your android.jar file into your "libs" folder of your project and then right click on that file and select the "build path" option then select the "add to build path"