# Classnotfound exception for working app

Tags: android

I have a strange issue.I developed an android application with scan functionality.I reused some zxing code code for the scanning section. My app is working fine for all the device and emulater too.But after I uploaded it in market I am getting error on scan portion.My error report is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2191)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9291)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2186)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.imotiva.Menu1.points(Menu1.java:46)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.qr.decoding.ResultMetadataType
at com.qr.scanning.CaptureActivity.<clinit>(CaptureActivity.java:92)
... 15 more
```

Still my code code is working in device but the same app in the market don't. Please help me friends...

Comment: Did you add you activity in manifest.xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Comment: @sarath is there zxing application install in your device? if yes then uninstall that application and recheck your code.

Comment: may be its because you have zxing installed on your device, it worked well

Comment: @ Android Coader..Yes I uninstald barcode scanner app.Then also I am getting error. But my local app with same code of market app is working fine

Comment: @gtumca-MAC....Sarath's error report is not mentioning about any jar and his localcode is working well for all device means???..The uploaded app only have the problem.

Comment: @gtumca-MAC...I am not using any external jars..

Comment: sometimes, a good software crash, it's because of the hardware.you see it easily when your app is installed on thousands devices.if the bug appear on a few devices and not on the other, it's not because of your app.

Comment: @VinceFR...Same device my local app working but market uploaded app is not..

Comment: @sarath local app worked in device without zxing , right ?? just for conformation.

Comment: @AndroidCoader...I cracked zing code and using the codes in my package...local app is working fine..market app only crashes

Comment: You're missing com.qr.decoding class in your APK

Comment: @CSmith..com.qr.decoding is a package.

Comment: Is there a difference in the build of the local and updated app? Stretching here...

Comment: @gtumca-MAC....pls post your reply as answer then only i can accept your reply as my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the solution for my problem.gtumca-MAC's solution [Android update 17 seems incompatible with external Jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046298/android-update-17-seems-incompatible-with-external-jars/10046725#10046725) worked for me.Created one folder named libs and add my core.jar .Now it's working fine.Thanks all.