# Reading PDF Document using iText in Android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I am currently testing samples of reading PDF using itext in android but i have a problem. The code below does not display anything in android emulator:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    PdfReader reader=null;
    String str= null;
    try {
         istr =(InputStream) assetManager.open("resume.pdf");
         reader=new PdfReader(istr);
         str = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1).toString();
         //str=reader.getPageContent(1).toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview);
    tv.setText(str);
}
```

The code is working but it does not display the contents of the PDF.

I think the problem here its not opening the PDF Document properly?

**My Goal here is to EXTRACT text from a PDF Document and Transfer it to a Variable in the Code then display it.**

I am using iText Version 5.3.3.

Comment: i think itext is not for reading pdf,you can use FBReader or Pdfviewr.

Comment: @Richa thank you for the reply. so your saying that iText can't Extract text from PDF Document and Transfer it to a variable in java/android?

Comment: @Christian It can extract text in Java if the PDF is suitable. A PDF containing a scanned image of some text, though, would not be suitable as iText does not do OCR. Maybe you want to post a sample PDF to inspect to tell you more.

Comment: @Christian Have you made sure that no exception has been caught in your code? Maybe instead of printing the stack trace you should (for the time being) set str to  "ERROR occured: " + e  or something like that and do some logging.

Comment: @mkl ooh. but it can read if a area is image or not?

Comment: @Christian iText can read the file if it contains images (I don't know, though, whether some additional dependencies are required on Android then) but it only knows the image as image, not as text.

Comment: @mkl i am trying to use [this](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itext/code/book/src/part4/chapter15/ExtractPageContentSorted2.java) and implement it in android but no luck.

Comment: @mkl btw how will i know if its working? i tried it in plain java (not android) and no outputs or any reactions

Comment: @mkl nevermind i got it. i forgot to refresh.

Comment: @Christian is your code working now?

Answer (score 2):

If your PDF is made with a PDF maker, so it is text and NOT a scanned document or other picture, this should do it:

```
                String content;
                PdfReader reader = null;
                try {
                    //String fileName is the string with the path to your .pdf file, for example resources/pdfs/preface.pdf
                    reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int numberOfPages = readerTest.getNumberOfPages();
                numberOfPages = numberOfPages + 1;
                for (int page = 1; page < numberOfPages; page++){
                    try {
                        String content1Page = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, page);
                        content = content + content1Page;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Now `String content` contains the text of the PDF.

EDIT: You could also first try to leave out the `toString()` method in this line: `str = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1).toString();`