# Add library to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, pdf, jar, pdfbox

I want to add a library (PDFBox: http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.html). But I think I'm doing something wrong. I did:project>properties>java build path> add external JARs> pdfbox-1.7.0.jar. But whenever I then launch my project in the emulator I'm getting this error (logcat)

```
07-28 08:08:51.793: D/ddm-heap(222): Got feature list request
07-28 08:08:57.413: I/dalvikvm(222): Could not find method org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load, referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:08:57.413: W/dalvikvm(222): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3152: Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;.load (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;
07-28 08:08:57.413: D/dalvikvm(222): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
07-28 08:08:57.413: D/dalvikvm(222): Making a copy of Lme/moop/mytwitter/MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask;.doInBackground code (169 bytes)
07-28 08:08:57.423: E/dalvikvm(222): Could not find class 'org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper', referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:08:57.423: W/dalvikvm(222): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 507 (Lorg/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper;) in Lme/moop/mytwitter/MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask;
07-28 08:08:57.423: D/dalvikvm(222): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0008
07-28 08:08:57.423: I/dalvikvm(222): Could not find method org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.getText, referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:08:57.423: W/dalvikvm(222): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3154: Lorg/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper;.getText (Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;)Ljava/lang/String;
07-28 08:08:57.423: D/dalvikvm(222): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
07-28 08:08:57.433: I/dalvikvm(222): Could not find method org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.close, referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:08:57.433: W/dalvikvm(222): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3151: Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;.close ()V
07-28 08:08:57.433: D/dalvikvm(222): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001b
07-28 08:08:57.473: W/dalvikvm(222): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
07-28 08:08:57.473: E/AndroidRuntime(222): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #1 exiting due to uncaught exception
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:66)
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-28 08:08:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(222):  ... 4 more
07-28 08:08:57.903: I/dalvikvm(222): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-28 08:08:58.195: I/dalvikvm(222): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-28 08:09:01.793: I/Process(222): Sending signal. PID: 222 SIG: 9
07-28 08:20:54.283: I/dalvikvm(249): Could not find method org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load, referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:20:54.293: W/dalvikvm(249): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3152: Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;.load (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;
07-28 08:20:54.293: D/dalvikvm(249): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
07-28 08:20:54.293: D/dalvikvm(249): Making a copy of Lme/moop/mytwitter/MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask;.doInBackground code (169 bytes)
07-28 08:20:54.293: E/dalvikvm(249): Could not find class 'org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper', referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:20:54.293: W/dalvikvm(249): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 507 (Lorg/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper;) in Lme/moop/mytwitter/MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask;
07-28 08:20:54.293: D/dalvikvm(249): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0008
07-28 08:20:54.293: I/dalvikvm(249): Could not find method org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.getText, referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:20:54.293: W/dalvikvm(249): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3154: Lorg/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper;.getText (Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;)Ljava/lang/String;
07-28 08:20:54.303: D/dalvikvm(249): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
07-28 08:20:54.303: I/dalvikvm(249): Could not find method org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.close, referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:20:54.303: W/dalvikvm(249): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3151: Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;.close ()V
07-28 08:20:54.303: D/dalvikvm(249): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001b
07-28 08:20:54.343: W/dalvikvm(249): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
07-28 08:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(249): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #1 exiting due to uncaught exception
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:66)
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-28 08:20:54.383: E/AndroidRuntime(249):  ... 4 more
07-28 08:20:54.593: I/dalvikvm(249): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-28 08:20:54.933: I/dalvikvm(249): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-28 08:22:02.364: I/dalvikvm(273): Could not find method org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load, referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:22:02.374: W/dalvikvm(273): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3152: Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;.load (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;
07-28 08:22:02.374: D/dalvikvm(273): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
07-28 08:22:02.374: D/dalvikvm(273): Making a copy of Lme/moop/mytwitter/MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask;.doInBackground code (169 bytes)
07-28 08:22:02.374: E/dalvikvm(273): Could not find class 'org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper', referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:22:02.374: W/dalvikvm(273): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 507 (Lorg/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper;) in Lme/moop/mytwitter/MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask;
07-28 08:22:02.374: D/dalvikvm(273): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0008
07-28 08:22:02.374: I/dalvikvm(273): Could not find method org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.getText, referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:22:02.374: W/dalvikvm(273): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3154: Lorg/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper;.getText (Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;)Ljava/lang/String;
07-28 08:22:02.384: D/dalvikvm(273): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
07-28 08:22:02.384: I/dalvikvm(273): Could not find method org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.close, referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:22:02.384: W/dalvikvm(273): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3151: Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;.close ()V
07-28 08:22:02.384: D/dalvikvm(273): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001b
07-28 08:22:02.424: W/dalvikvm(273): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
07-28 08:22:02.424: E/AndroidRuntime(273): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #1 exiting due to uncaught exception
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:66)
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-28 08:22:02.554: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  ... 4 more
07-28 08:22:02.664: I/dalvikvm(273): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-28 08:22:02.924: I/dalvikvm(273): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-28 08:22:05.184: I/Process(273): Sending signal. PID: 273 SIG: 9
07-28 08:33:06.073: I/dalvikvm(300): Could not find method org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load, referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:33:06.073: W/dalvikvm(300): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3152: Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;.load (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;
07-28 08:33:06.073: D/dalvikvm(300): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
07-28 08:33:06.073: D/dalvikvm(300): Making a copy of Lme/moop/mytwitter/MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask;.doInBackground code (169 bytes)
07-28 08:33:06.073: E/dalvikvm(300): Could not find class 'org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper', referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:33:06.073: W/dalvikvm(300): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 507 (Lorg/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper;) in Lme/moop/mytwitter/MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask;
07-28 08:33:06.073: D/dalvikvm(300): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0008
07-28 08:33:06.083: I/dalvikvm(300): Could not find method org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.getText, referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:33:06.083: W/dalvikvm(300): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3154: Lorg/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper;.getText (Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;)Ljava/lang/String;
07-28 08:33:06.083: D/dalvikvm(300): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
07-28 08:33:06.083: I/dalvikvm(300): Could not find method org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.close, referenced from method me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground
07-28 08:33:06.083: W/dalvikvm(300): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3151: Lorg/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument;.close ()V
07-28 08:33:06.083: D/dalvikvm(300): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001b
07-28 08:33:06.123: W/dalvikvm(300): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
07-28 08:33:06.123: E/AndroidRuntime(300): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #1 exiting due to uncaught exception
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:66)
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at me.moop.mytwitter.MainActivity$CheckScheduleChangeTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-28 08:33:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(300):  ... 4 more
07-28 08:33:06.453: I/dalvikvm(300): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-28 08:33:06.623: I/dalvikvm(300): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-28 08:33:08.723: I/Process(300): Sending signal. PID: 300 SIG: 9
```

So it can't find the classes I imported from the aditional library. When I open the .jar in the java build path screen it says this:

Source attachment: (None)

Javadoc Location: (None)

Native library location: (None)

Access rules: (No restrictions)

Is that normal?

Could anyone tell me excactly which files I need to download from that website (http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.html) and which files I have to add in which screen and how.

THANK YOU!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ADT r17 you should no longer add library files to your project like this. This is now handled automatically by ADT.

In order to add an external library to your project you have to create a folder called `libs` in the root folder of your project (the folder where your `src` folder is located). The next step is to copy all libraries (jars) to that folder. The rest is done automatically for you. No need to edit build path, etc.

Comment: My project already contains a map called libs, can I use that one as well?

Comment: Hmm, I tried it (pasting the .jar in the libs folder which was already created), but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: good to know, i followed a website telling me how to install libs which was hugely complex, and it turns out, wrong! http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/10601-how-make-apache-commons-stringutils-etc-work-eclipse.html people should remove out of data info like this

Answer (score 0):

Buddy try this way

```
Right click on Yout project  -> Click on New -> goto Folder -> Give Folder name
```

To Add **.jars** in **libs folder**

```
Right click on res folder -> Goto Build path -> click on Add External jar
```

**or**

```
Right click on res folder -> Goto Build path -> Configure build path -> From Left side menu Select "Java Build path" ->There will be 4 tabs Click on Libraries -> Click on Add Externals JARs..
```