# NoClassDefFound error when setting up tcp server

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, tcpserver

I am creating a tcp server that communicates with C# and I accessed the coding from this [website](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/340714/Android-How-to-communicate-with-NET-application-vi). I have downloaded the source code and added the external jars that were in the source code. Every time I try to run the server code on my app I get the `NoClassDefFound` in my LogCat. I was told this might have something to do with my buildpath which is why I mentioned the external jars. I have included my LogCat, Manifest, and Java. Thanks for the help.

```
08-06 13:31:54.989: W/dalvikvm(5164): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401f3760)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.com.proto1.AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivityInner$1
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at com.example.com.proto1.AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivityInner.<init>(AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivityInner.java:102)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1301)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1733)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1834)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1027)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
08-06 13:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

:31:54.989: E/AndroidRuntime(5164):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

The Java

```
    package com.example.com.proto1;

import eneter.messaging.diagnostic.EneterTrace;
import eneter.messaging.endpoints.typedmessages.*;
import eneter.messaging.messagingsystems.messagingsystembase.*;
import eneter.messaging.messagingsystems.tcpmessagingsystem.TcpMessagingSystemFactory;
import eneter.net.system.EventHandler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivityInner extends Activity {

    // UI controls
    private Handler myRefresh = new Handler();
    private EditText myMessageTextEditText;
    private EditText myResponseEditText;
    private Button mySendRequestBtn;

    // Sender sending MyRequest and as a response receiving MyResponse.
    private IDuplexTypedMessageSender<MyResponse, MyRequest> mySender;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tcp_server);

        // Get UI widgets.
        myMessageTextEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageTextEditText);
        myResponseEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageLengthEditText);
        mySendRequestBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendRequestBtn);

        // Subscribe to handle the button click.
        mySendRequestBtn.setOnClickListener(myOnSendRequestClickHandler);

        try {
            openConnection();
        } catch (Exception err) {
            EneterTrace.error("Open connection failed.", err);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Stop listening to response messages.
        mySender.detachDuplexOutputChannel();
    }

    private void openConnection() throws Exception {
        // Create sender sending MyRequest and as a response receiving
        // MyResponse
        IDuplexTypedMessagesFactory aSenderFactory = new DuplexTypedMessagesFactory();
        mySender = aSenderFactory.createDuplexTypedMessageSender(
                MyResponse.class, MyRequest.class);

        // Subscribe to receive response messages.
        mySender.responseReceived().subscribe(myOnResponseHandler);

        // Create TCP messaging for the communication.
        // Note: 10.0.2.2 is a special alias to the loopback (127.0.0.1)
        // on the development machine
        IMessagingSystemFactory aMessaging = new TcpMessagingSystemFactory();
        IDuplexOutputChannel anOutputChannel = aMessaging
                .createDuplexOutputChannel("tcp://70.63.35.218/");

        // Attach the output channel to the sender and be able to send
        // messages and receive responses.
        mySender.attachDuplexOutputChannel(anOutputChannel);
    }

    private void onSendRequest(View v) {
        // Create the request message.
        MyRequest aRequestMsg = new MyRequest();
        aRequestMsg.Text = myMessageTextEditText.getText().toString();

        // Send the request message.
        try {
            mySender.sendRequestMessage(aRequestMsg);
        } catch (Exception err) {
            EneterTrace.error("Sending the message failed.", err);
        }
    }

    private void onResponseReceived(Object sender,
            final TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse> e) {
        // Display the result - returned number of characters.
        // Note: Marshal displaying to the correct UI thread.
        myRefresh.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                myResponseEditText.setText(Integer.toString(e
                        .getResponseMessage().Length));
            }
        });
    }

    private EventHandler<TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse>> myOnResponseHandler

    = new EventHandler<TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse>>() {
        public void onEvent(Object sender,
                TypedResponseReceivedEventArgs<MyResponse> e) {
            onResponseReceived(sender, e);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener myOnSendRequestClickHandler = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onSendRequest(v);
        }
    };
}
```

MyRequest Java

```
  package com.example.com.proto1;


public class MyRequest {
    // Request message type
    // The message must have the same name as declared in the service.
    // Also, if the message is the inner class, then it must be static.
    public String Text;
}
```

MyResponse Java

```
  package com.example.com.proto1;


public class MyResponse {
    // Request message type
    // The message must have the same name as declared in the service.
    // Also, if the message is the inner class, then it must be static.
    public int Length;
}
```

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716) answer that may help you

Comment: is the class eneter.net.system.EventHandler present? I think there is some problem referencing EventHandler

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I'm fairly new so you'll have to be specific with me

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact answer but i can give you a pointer:

The missing class is `com.example.com.proto1.AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivity$1`, since it ends with a '$1' it means it is the inner class of `AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivity`.

That Inner class should have a separate file called `AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivity$1.class` , so it seems that for some reason this file is not being generated.

You can try and extract the inner classes to an actual classes and see if that helps, or try to find out why the inner class file is not generated.

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE**

The comments are getting too long so i'll try and explain what i mean:

Inside of `AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivityInner` you have to inner classes declared: MyRequest,MyResponse.

You need to create 2 new java files: MyRequest.java and MyResponse.java and copy the code to them, so it'll look like:

**MyRequest.java**

```
 public class MyRequest {
        public String Text;
    }
```

**MyResponse.java**

```
public class MyResponse {
        public int Length;
    }
```

Then, **DELETE** those inner classes from `AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivityInner` and instead import the newly created classes, compile and redeploy the code.

Comment: How do I extract the inner class?

Comment: Just create another java file and copy paste the code from the inner class. but remove the static declaration from the class.

Comment: Ok, I did that. Now what do I do?

Comment: I'm assuming you removed the inner class definition and you are using the newly created class instead, just deploy the new code and try using it.

Comment: have done that and I updated my question coding. I think I am just getting the same error but with my new class

Comment: Have you updated the code? it looks exactly the same to me. you still have inner classes declared

Comment: Ok, it is completely updated now. I removed all of the static declarations but I still have the error

Comment: ok, I have applied your new directions and updated the coding in the question

Comment: No, you got it completely wrong! just create the classes as i posted, they don't need to inherit Activity and they don't need all that code, just as i posted.

Comment: Ok, I updated. You'll have to forgive my slowness. I'm still pretty now to development

Comment: I tried to deploy it but it failed. When I said I updated it that included my logcat. I should have been clearer

Comment: You are still extending Activity in MyRequest and MyResponse, remove the `extends Activity` from thos classes, leave it only in your main class `AndroidNetCommunicationClientActivityInner`