# Javadoc for ORMlite attached, but not found by Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, javadoc, ormlite

I am using ORMlite 4.41 for Android in Eclipse. Can't seem to get the javadoc to work in Eclipse. I am using the following to ORMlite jars:

- ormlite-android-4.41.jar
- ormlite-core-4.41.jar

I have downloaded the corresponding javadoc jars, and imported them into a "javadoc" folder in the root directory of my project.

- ormlite-android-4.41-javadoc.jar
- ormlite-core-4.41-javadoc.jar

Using "Build Path" --> "Libraries", I correctly set the Javadoc location for both jars to the workspace instance of the appropriate jar. I even used "validate" and Eclipse says it looks valid.

I have cleaned and rebuilt my project, and started eclipse new, but whenever I hover over ORMlite ojects in code, I still get "This element neither attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have also tried specifying the ormlite online javadoc, which also "validates", but again, Eclipse does not recognize it.

Answer (score 1):

[try this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005089/class-not-found-exception-on-android-when-i-use-extends-ormlitebaseactivitydata)

in your project add a folder libs and copy required ormlite libraries in that folder

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell your ormlite jar-file, where its javadoc is.

You can do this like shown in the picture below:

- In your package explorer: right click on the ormlite-core-x.xx.jar
- Select "Properties"
- Go to the "Javadoc Location" tab
- Enter the Location of your ormlite-core-x.xx-**javadoc**.jar
- Click [OK]  -> done, you should now see the javadoc on hovering

[image: Screenshot of the necessary properties settings]