# Jar not found error in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

In the following code below i have importted the jsch jar by clicking on Project properties and by adding the "add external jar button" also have added into the ant global path from the following link [Add external jar](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.in/2011/04/javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html)  but when i run the program i still get the  "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jcraft.jsch.JSch"

```
 package android_jsch.com;


  import java.io.PrintStream;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.widget.EditText;

  public class Android_jschActivity extends Activity {
     EditText ip,username,password;
     @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
          commands.add("touch /tmp/test1.txt");
          commands.add("touch /tmp/test2.txt");
          commands.add("touch /tmp/test3.txt");
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
        rd);

          try {
              JSch jsch = new JSch();


              session.connect();

              Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");//only shell
              channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
              PrintStream shellStream = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());  // printStream for convenience
              channel.connect();
              for(String command: commands) {
                  shellStream.println(command);
                  shellStream.flush();
              }

              Thread.sleep(5000);

              channel.disconnect();
              session.disconnect();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              System.err.println("ERROR: Connecting via shell to "+ip.getText().toString());
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }


      private static void setUpHostKey(Session session) {
          java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
          config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
          session.setConfig(config);
      }

     }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify that the jar must be exported when building apk: in "Java Build Path" > "Order and Export" tab, fill the checkbox corresponding to your jar.

Comment: yes i did select the check box there but the error still exists

Comment: did you try cleaning your project after doing it?

Comment: s i did and have run it.Wait i will let you know what all i have selected in the order and export tab

Comment: YEs it is working now after i did multiple cleans.But the APP doesnt seem to connect to the external system.Any idea why??

Comment: It's probably a different problem now... Try to identify it and post a new question (with log traces) if necessary