# GCM: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

Please help, it's all the days that I work on this problem and used all possible solutions found on the web.

Requirements:
Use juno eclipse, ADT 20
I have works with business GCM, I did a project a bit more complicated using the demo of Android developers
(http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html)
And I realized that my application was in Crask each call class GCMRegistrar.

So I created a minimal exercise that will work if I unlock everything.

```
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

    public class Manda extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_manda);

        crash --->  GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

            // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.

            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

        }
```

I attach the screenshot of the min exercise
I added the gcm.jar library and I did all I found.

I am a new user than I can not post img but I put a public link of bropbox 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dyi0y4sppz4rcq3/img%20GCM%20problem.zip

Comment: may [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716) will help you

Comment: the problem was my emulator without Google Apis (Google Inc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my emulator without Google Apis (Google Inc).
If you are using android emulator you have to create emulator with Google Apis (Google Inc).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Google's docs, you MUST add your AndroidManifast.xml file the following:

```
<service android:name="YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME.GCMIntentService" />

<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="YOUR_CATEGORY_NAME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Make sure you put your IntentService class in the right package.

In addition, how did you add the gcm.jar to you project?
You need to create a "libs" folder in your project and put the jar there

Comment: Dealr Yuval, I took the manifest from http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html. I have only one package in my simply project. I think the problem in in the library... I added: Build Path --> Libraris--> and i added the jar....the libs folder there is in my project of Default... However i putted in this folder too...

Comment: But does your classes are located in the same packages as the example?

Comment: In addition, it looks like a build path error, where did you locate the gcm.jar file?

Comment: can I add some scranshop in dropbox?

Comment: However my class is in the main package and my jar is in "..\workspace\SendGCM\libs"

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

1. Check that  you have put **gcm.jar** file inside **libs** and **not lib folder.**

**Solution 2:**

Mostly this is the problem.Follow below steps to resolve the problem:

1. Right click on **Project**->**Build Path**-> **Configure Build Path** and then **Order and Exports**
2. Now check the **Android Private Libraries** .The **checkbox** should check of **required library.**
3. Refresh ,Clean and Run..here you go!

Comment: Thanks a lot. the problem was my emulator without Google Apis (Google Inc)