# Exact procedure to add "jfeinstein10 / SlidingMenu" in android project

Tags: android, android-layout

I am totally new to android, i am trying to implement `Sliding Menu having ListView with 
Swipe Gesture`, by some searching i found that    https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu
is exactly what i want,

There are many questions related to this which are guiding how integrate this library with project, but none of them are for new person like me. also procedure given on github is not detailed, all i know is how to add .jar file but this .zip and other things are totally new for me

This is what i have done till yet;

1. downloaded zip from above link
2. Extracted that link to folder
3. in Eclipse File->import->existing project into work-space..

Now it is showing me many error in package `library.src.com.slidingmenu.lib.app`

e.g

`The declared package "com.slidingmenu.lib.app" does not match the expected package "library.src.com.slidingmenu.lib.app"`

now i don't  know what to do...

please somebody guide me with proper detailed procedure of how to integrate and use this library in project.

Thanks !

Comment: Which eclipse version are you using ?

Comment: @Saurabh Bayani  eclipse ganymede

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Well, spending 3 days with same problem I found the exact procedure for this thing. The guide on [github](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) is of-course not for entry level guys like us, also there is no such a "step-by-step tutorial" for this, so it took time.

Important: I didn't include "`Sherlock ActionBar`" library, because I want to keep it simple

- First up all update your eclipse to latest `ADT` or best way you can download [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) `ADT Bundle`, and confirm that everything is running fine in new `ADTBundle`.
- Download latest "[zip for  jfeinstein10 / SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/archive/master.zip)" from "[gitHub](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)", And extract it anywhere you want. After extraction it must have these files and folders inside.

[image: Folder after extracting library]

- Now open your eclipse `File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace`, Browse to your folder most probably "`SlidingMenu-master`" and you should see following

[image]

Hit `Finish`, If eclipse shows some error like `Unable to resolve target` then change your target through `Right Click on project -> Properties -> Android` and check any latest `google API` your SDK have.

- Add `Dependency`, by right clicking on `project -> properties -> android -> library -> add -> SlidingMenuActivity`, and clear both projects.
- Add new XML layout named as `menu_frame` in your `res -> layout` and put following in it
  Put `Frame Layout` and `list view` in it.
- Also add a `ListView` in your `mainActivity` XML file.
- Now it is time to create "Menu" write following code in your `onCreate()` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

  ```
  SlidingMenu menu;
  menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
  menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
  menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
  menu.setShadowWidth(5);
  menu.setFadeDegree(0.0f);
  menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
  menu.setBehindWidth(200);
  menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);
  ```
- At the lines it is showing error press `ctrl+1` and import `com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;`"
- Run your project and you should see menu coming out from left side
- Now the next task is to add `adapter` and `listener` for both of your ListViews (i.e for Main-screen and Menu).

For information about function used while creating Menu you can refer to example apps provided with library or google them, there is lot of info available.

Also thanks to "Jeremy Feinstein" for such a great library

Comment: Hi , tanks for tutorial , how can i add item and Listner for  ListViiew(Menu) is it possible in main activity ?

Comment: @mahdi, yes ! it is possible. listview in your Menu is treated same as a normal list-view that you have on your activity. So procedure is also same, just google for adding listener to listview and replace name of that list-view with your list-view, and you are done !

Comment: @SaurabhBayani , i use this code to add items to my ListViews (menu & Main Screen) but it`s only work for main screen !

Answer (score 0):

I believe you imported the package with a different package name.

> The declared package "com.slidingmenu.lib.app" does not match the expected package "library.src.com.slidingmenu.lib.app"

Rename it from *com.slidingmenu.lib.app* to *library.src.com.slidingmenu.lib.app* and see if that resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need only import the project inside the "library" folder

Comment: Can you be little more specific ? i mean there are many folder in that zip folder, which one should i import in my lib folder ?

Comment: like @john44 told you, unzip the SlidingMenu from jFeinStein and import just the folder "library" from the unzipped folder. Define it as a library in the propreties and import it in your project. It might be usefull, to import the Example too for better understanding of the different possibilities, but to be true, for the beginning It might be too confusing and better to go the way just explained at the top.

Answer (score 0):

i use this code to add items to my ListViews (menu & Main Screen) but it`s only work for main screen

```
final Context context = this ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    String[] items = new String[]{"xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items); 
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_frame, null);
    ListView lv2 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv2.setText("Hello Mahdi");
    String[] items2 = new String[]{"xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items2); 
    lv2.setAdapter(adapter2);


    SlidingMenu menu;
    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidth(5);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.0f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setBehindWidth(200);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);
}
```

Comment: Try adding your adapters after the `menu.setMenu()`.

Comment: @mahdi can you explain it further, I'm looking out for something similar but cant quite get it..