# jfeinsteins slide menu implementation java/ adding a library as a dependency

Tags: java, android, implementation, slidingmenu

So I'm trying to implement jfeinsteins slide menu into my application, but before I do that I want to get a good demo, so I know how to implement it.  Problem is that I'm stuck.

this is where I'm getting the library.
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

This is the project I'm trying to implement it in. 
https://github.com/baruckis/Android-SlidingMenuImplementation

I did this part for the set up.
In Eclipse, just import the library as an Android library project. Project > Clean to generate the binaries you need, like R.java, etc.

,but I'm not sure I'm completely understanding this part.

Then, just add SlidingMenu as a dependency to your existing project and you're good to go!

how do I add slidingMenu as a dependency.  Also, the error I'm receiving is SlidingMenu cannot be resolved to a variable, SlidingMenu cannot be resolved to a type.

Please can someone help me answer this!?  Am I close?

Comment: This is fix my problem, check it:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14118683/2430217

Answer (score 0):

To add a dependancy to an existing project, select the project containing your code (the one you want the dependancy to attach to), right click the project in the Package Explorer and select Properties.

In the Properties window, select Android and ensure that the library projects are added in the Library section. Click add to add an existing project in the workspace to the project as a dependancy.

It may also be worth checking dependancies in the Java Build Path too. Here you can ensure the correct .jar files are correctly assigned to your projects.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at this place too. Please follow the below steps.

1. After downloading the library. In eclipse, go to New->project->android existing project
2. After downloading SlidingMenuImplementation, add this to eclipse similar to the way above.

I hope till here you have done. Next, right click on the SlidingMenuImplementation project --> properties --> Android --> Below the target window, you'll find references.

Add the Slidemenu library there. Once done clean the project. The errors are gone.

Please note, this supports only Android 4 and above. For lower versions use ActionBarSherlock.