# Unfortunately, app has stopped working error

Tags: android, eclipse, tags, slidingmenu

I have followed the guide from this site [Exact procedure to add "jfeinstein10 / SlidingMenu" in android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057367/exact-procedure-to-add-jfeinstein10-slidingmenu-in-android-project) to put a sliding menu into my android app. I have received no errors and however when I run it it gives me the error that it has stopped.I am using a running device to run the app which is a galaxy s4. I am using the latest android eclipse and the latest sdk and JDK 7. I am also running ubuntu 14.04. Your help is greatly apreciated. Thank you

Comment: Examine LogCat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0):

i recommend for you android native navigation drawer, its awesome work, check out from here

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: i downloaded the .zip file but it doesnt say how to use it in eclipse on ubuntu. do you mind giving a step by step guide on how i do it?

Comment: if in your system eclipse installed then it is easy to import and use