# Android Objects of SlidingMenu cannot resolved to an type

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu

I already saw, there are a lot of threads handeling the same problem as I got, but it seems to different.
The problem I've got is, that after importing the libary project of SlidingMenu it will show up errors (as usually) but if I select the Google APIs it wont change. I tried the API 16 & 17.
I also cleaned up the code, tried to import via File -> Import or the "New" Button -> Android Project From Existing Code
Nothing worked, if I check the errors inside the project, the classes are in the wrong package and a lot of objects can't be resolved to an type
I've also tried to use actionbarsherlock, changes nothing for me.

Thank you for reading :)
Julian

Comment: Tried Project -> Clean ?

Comment: this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991496/how-to-set-up-jfeinstein10-sliding-menu-on-android-eclipse) may help

Comment: Yeah already cleaned...

Comment: Thank you bakriOnFire that was really helpfull, don't know why but I needed to move every class of the library to another package -.-