# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - Android - Wikitude

Tags: android, wikitude

This's my first post..
I have a problem with my android app (about augmented reality using Wikitude)
this is what is shown in logcat:

```
03-19 17:04:06.870: E/AndroidRuntime(15789): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 17:04:06.870: E/AndroidRuntime(15789): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tirocinio.myapp.wikitude.RealtaAumentataActivity
```

this is the class that handles the augmented reality, or at least should do:
(I post only the onCreate() method:)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.....
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aractivity);
    this.architectView = (ArchitectView) this.findViewById(R.id.architectView);
    architectView.onCreate(apiKey);
......
 }
```

this is the "aractivity" file xml:

```
### aractivity.xml ###


<com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView
    android:id="@+id/architectView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView>
```

These're the import:

```
### import ###

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import tirocinio.myapp.R;
import tirocinio.myapp.activity.PoiDetailActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectUrlListener;
import com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView;
```

This's my Manifest: I think it's correct

```
### Manifest ###

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tirocinio.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="tirocinio.myapp.activity.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="tirocinio.myapp.activity.MappaActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="tirocinio.myapp.wikitude.RealtaAumentataActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this's the buildpath:

```
### buildpath ###

 - maps.jar
 - QCAR.jar
 - wikitudes.jar
 - Android Dipendences
 - Google APIs [Android 4.2.2]
```

Comment: is your view `ArchitectView` placed in correct package as used in xml? can you post the imports of your activity code too?

Comment: Your Manifest file might be missing the activity definition for RealtaAumentataActivity

Comment: Could you post you buildpath? My gues is that you included the augmented reality class jar, but it isn't properly added to your buildpath.

Comment: I edited the page, because I could not answer.

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! I finally solved my problem thanks to you!!