# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files vs. E/AndroidRuntime( 1015): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I have an application using the hidden `nfc_extras` API on Android 4.4.

I do not use the Java Reflection, meaning I re-package the `com.android.nfc_extras.jar` file and use it in Eclipse as a referenced library.

My application starts two different activities depending on the choice (button) done from the `MainActivity` layout. This means I also need the `android-support-v4.jar` library (it was automatically included in my `libs` folder by Eclipse).
It needs to be signed before being installed.

If on *Build Path->Configure Build Path -> Order And Export*, the `com.android.nfc_extras.jar` file is clicked, then when I want to do *Export -> Export Android Application*, I get the following error:

```
[Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/nfc_extras/EeIOException;
```

If the `com.android.nfc_extras.jar` file is not clicked, the export/signing is OK but at execution, I have the following errors (among others):

```
W/dalvikvm( 1015): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/android/nfc_extras/NfcAdapterExtras;)
...
E/AndroidRuntime( 1015): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.nfc_extras.NfcAdapterExtras
```

I have another application that only makes use of the `com.android.nfc_extras.jar` library and not the `android-support-v4.jar` one, so I am wondering if the problem comes from that.

Comment: You should look at [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716) answer

Comment: I tried and added the com.android.nfc_extras.jar in my libs folder. I removed it as a Referenced Library.

Comment: But I still get the W/dalvikvm(  932): VFY: unable to resolve static method 21: Lcom/android/nfc_extras/NfcAdapterExtras;.get (Landroid/nfc/NfcAdapter;)Lcom/android/nfc_extras/NfcAdapterExtras; and 01-02 00:01:54.937 E/AndroidRuntime(  932): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.nfc_extras.NfcAdapterExtras errors.

Comment: I also tried to click the Android Private Libraries in Build Path -> Order and Export, but in this case I get the [2014-01-13 15:26:33 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/nfc_extras/EeIOException;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer to my issue. Nothing to do with libraries, I simply missed the

```
<uses-library android:name="com.android.nfc_extras" android:required="true" />
```

in my Manifest...

Comment: Please use code formatting `:)` [no need to reply this comment]