# Converting JPG to PDF

Tags: android, pdf, itext

Convert JPG to PDF is throwing exception at line `Document.open()`

```
com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance( document, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
document.open();
Image image = Image.getInstance(updPath);
document.add(image);
document.close();
```

I added the itext as external jar file

Comment: `throwing exception at line Document.open() `. You mean document.open()? Then what has this to do with converting a jpg?

Comment: problem solved 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046298/android-update-17-seems-incompatible-with-external-jars/10046725#10046725
Thanks guys for voting minus it will help me for my future questions

Comment: I dont know why people rating minus. if i am new on stackoverflow what is the use of this site for me as i am not able to give answer due to some people rating me

Comment: @kamleshwerpurohit Fortunately, up votes give you more reputation than down votes. You now have two up votes and they outweigh the single down vote ;-)

Comment: So can we close this as an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10046298/2564301? (If the answer there solved this issue for you. I can't really follow because you gave virtually no relevant info.)

Comment: Yes We can close it thank you so much for up votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for above problem. I just added the jar in libs folder it works for me. 
Please See Reference [Android update 17 seems incompatible with external Jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046298/android-update-17-seems-incompatible-with-external-jars/10046725#10046725)

There may be problem with external jars,

in your project just

- create a folder named libs.
- Copy and paste all needed external jar files into that folder.